# how to make a project in Github with multiple repositories?

Tags: github, repository

hey so we are working on our graduation project and we wanted to put everything on Github from the start so we have a backend side that two guys will work on and the mobile app which I will be working on with another guy so my question is **how to put those two repositories together in one place** and make each repository with multiple contributors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only solution is to use organizations. Create an organization and add your different repositories in that organization.

https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations/creating-a-new-organization-from-scratch

Comment: You're welcome. You should select my answer as the selected answer to help others when they search this.

Comment: That really sucks. In gitlab we can create subgroups. I really don't know which invite github is waiting to make this feature available.